# Salesforce SDK is not opening login screen

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I am new to salesforce i have to interface salesforce with my android app. I am following this tutorial [Interfacing Salesforce with Android](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/06/interfacing-salesforce-with-android.html)

I have successfully created connected app on salesforce now i am creating android i have followed above tutorial and official salesforce documentation.

I have tried following

1. I have added cordova and salesforce sdk to my android project
2. Created bootconfig.xml in values folder with my connected app details

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="remoteAccessConsumerKey">3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrBxQwpiktQclW3vqaOIgDE9XorTmWJ.VoMDc_53UJLeQFrTH.FYD_jsBH8TzhAO3YWRbxSJ
</string>
    <string name="oauthRedirectURI">sfdc://helloworld</string>
    <string-array name="oauthScopes">
        <item>chatter_api</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="androidPushNotificationClientId"></string>

</resources>
```

3. My application class implementation is following

```html
public class BSDApplication extends Application
{

    class KeyImpl implements KeyInterface {


        @Override
        public String getKey(String name) {
            return Encryptor.hash(name + "12s9adpahk;n12-97sdainkasd=012", name + "12kl0dsakj4-cxh1qewkjasdol8");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside oncreate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("BSDAPP", "before login for salesforce");
        try {
            SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), new KeyImpl(), MainActivity.class);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("BSDAPP","salesforceException "+e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.d("BSDAPP","login for salesforce");
    }
}
```

4. I can see the logs but as per documentation before proceeding  my app's Main activity class it should display login screen but it directly move to my screen.

What i am missing here?  Any help any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the name of your application class in your manifest file. that could be the reason of direct setup to your app login screen rather than Salesforce login screen.

```
  <application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="com.yourpackage.yourApplicationClass"        android:manageSpaceActivity="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.ManageSpaceActivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/sf__icon">
```